# Do Google Custom Search JSON API purchased additional queries rollover?

Tags: google-custom-search

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) for Google Custom Search JSON/ATOM API  is unclear regarding pricing for additional queries. It states:

> The API provides 100 search queries per day for free. If you need
>   more, you may sign up for billing in the API Console. Additional
>   requests cost $5 per 1000 queries, up to 10k queries per day.

For those that use that API in excess of the initial free 100, does the $5/1000 additional queries reset each day, or does that number roll over for subsequent days?

For instance, if I have a total number of queries on 3 consecutive days of 110, 120, and 130, will the account be billed $5 each day for the 10, 20, and 30 extra queries? Or will I be billed $5 the first day and by the end of the 3rd day I'll still have a bucket of 940 additional queries left to use for future overages?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is also still looking for an answer to this question, (as I was a day ago), it turns out that for the Google Custom Search API the billing for $5/1000 queries is prorated.
Google Cloud Support emailed me the following:

> With the Google Custom Search, you have a free 100 search queries per day which resets daily. But for example if you exceeded the daily limit, you will be charged $5 per 1,000 queries. In case that you go over the 100 queries per day and did not reach the 1,000 queries, it will be prorated from the $5. This resets daily as well. Please take note that 10k queries is the maximum daily.

I then clarified with them the following example, which they agreed was correct.

An example of making an average of 180 JSON API queries/day:

- 100 queries/day are free
- 80 queries/day are charged at $5 * (80/1000) = $0.40/day
- Monthly it would be $12.00 (40cents * 30)

Comment: @LipsumIpsum After Google Support's response quoted above, I literally put the $12 example in my reply email to double-check if I had it exactly correct, and the support person said it was accurate.